# Tomcat not compressing js files

Tags: javascript, jsp, tomcat, compression

I used gzip compression in tomcat for my website. Below is the connector code-

```
 <Connector SSLEnabled="true" clientAuth="false" maxThreads="150"   port="9093" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="https" secure="true" sslProtocol="TLS"
     compression="on"
    compressionMinSize="2048"
    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
    compressableMimeType="text/html,text/xml,text/css,text/javascript, application/x-javascript,application/javascript"
    />
```

I checked size of one js file in browser console before compression. It was around 157KB and that time content-encoding was not present.

Then I implemented compression, checked size again and it was same i.e 157KB. This time content-encoding was present i.e gzip
It means gzip compression implemented but js file didn't compress. 
Why? Any alternate?

Comment: What version of tomcat are you using? What do the HTTP headers look like?

Comment: Are you checking both the "size" and the "content" fields for the resource in network requests in the dev console?

Comment: @reto Tomcat v7.0 and header contains this, Content-Encoding:"gzip", Content-Type:"text/html;charset=UTF-8", Transfer-Encoding:"chunked", Vary:"Accept-Encoding", X-Frame-Options:"SAMEORIGIN"

Comment: @RahulNanwani Yeah, I am checking both fields

Comment: Then is the "size" less than the "content" when you have gzip encoding. With gzip encoding, the size should be less than the content (even with browser cache disabled)

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the option `useSendfile="off"` in `Connector` sector? Files larger than 48KB may not be compressed even if `compression="on"`.

See Tomcat conf-ref https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/http.html and search `compression`.

Comment: `useSenfile="off" ` worked!